# Opera: Have links and results from the search box open in a new tab

Tags: opera, opera-10

Is there any way to type into the opera search box or address bar and have the result open in a new tab by default (i.e. when I simply hit enter)? (Opera 10.52 beta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just press **Shift+Enter** instead of **Enter** and you'll get what you want.

This key combination works for any search box or address bar since earliest Opera releases.

EDIT: Also if you copy the address or search words to clipboard you can press **Ctrl+Shift+V** instead of standard **Ctrl+V** and **Shift+Enter** key combinations. This will paste text and open the result in new tab immediately. Try it.

Comment: what i'm trying to do is have it work with just enter (e.g. firefox has an option to interchange the actions of ctrl-enter and enter). i want the default to be open in new tab.

Comment: You can do that for Search boxes only but not for address bar. Press Ctrl+12, go to upper 'Tabs' item, and uncheck the checkmark saying something like 'Reuse current tab'.